# Python - Pandas replace a value in a column if another column has a value that is in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have hundreds of thousands of rows that look something like this (there's actually more data than just this, but I'm trying to simplify the idea I've been attempting)...

```
index  status       location
0      infected     area5
1      healthy      area6
2      healthy      area3
3      infected     area8
4      healthy      area1
5      healthy      area8
6      healthy      area5
7      healthy      area2
8      healthy      area4
9      healthy      area10
10     ....          ....
```

I'm trying to update the `status` column, based on if an area is infected. So I basically made a list of the infected areas:

```
infected_areas = ['area5', 'area8']
```

Then what I'm trying to do is look at all the rows (or really just the 'healthy' rows), and if any of those match to what is in my `infected_areas` list, to change that `status` to infected.

So with my example above, the output should look like:

```
index  status       location
0      infected     area5
1      healthy      area6
2      healthy      area3
3      infected     area8
4      healthy      area1
5      infected     area8
6      infected     area5
7      healthy      area2
8      healthy      area4
9      healthy      area10
10     ....          ....
```

here's what I've been working with, but not quite getting anywhere:

`df[df['location'].isin(location)]['status'] = 'infected'

Comment: There is no code here.  Is this a pandas question?

Comment: yes, sorry. it is with pandas. I was trying the .isin but to no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) in conjunction with [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
infected_areas = ['area5', 'area8']

df.status.where(
    ~df.location.str.strip().isin(infected_areas),
    other='infected',
    inplace=True)
>>> df
    index   status  location
0   0   infected    area5
1   1   healthy area6
2   2   healthy area3
3   3   infected    area8
4   4   healthy area1
5   5   infected    area8
6   6   infected    area5
7   7   healthy area2
8   8   healthy area4
9   9   healthy area10
```

Answer (score 4):

Just using `.loc`

```
df.loc[df.location.isin(infected_areas),'status']='infected'
df
Out[49]: 
   index    status location
0      0  infected    area5
1      1   healthy    area6
2      2   healthy    area3
3      3  infected    area8
4      4   healthy    area1
5      5  infected    area8
6      6  infected    area5
7      7   healthy    area2
8      8   healthy    area4
9      9   healthy   area10
```